# Cached arrays for subcomputation results in Parallel.For/Foreach

Tags: c#, .net, performance, parallel.foreach

I have a method that calculates some arrays in each iteration, then sums them (adding each array index-wise) and returns the array of sums.

I'm looking for a performant parallel method of doing so. In essence I want to avoid creating arrays constantly and reuse them instead.

Example:

```
private void Computation(float[] result)
{
  var _lock = new object();
  Parallel.For(0, 50, x =>
  {
    var subResult = new float[200*1000];
    CalculateSubResult(subResult);

    lock(_lock)
       for (int i = 0; i < subResult.Length; i++)
          result[i] += subResult[i];


  });
}
```

The problem is that these `Parallel.For's` are nested (because `CalculateSubResult` also does similar loop). This leads to constant creating and discarding arrays which are used to hold subcomputation results.

To Get around this, im using `ThreadLocal` to store cached arrays:

```
ThreadLocal<float[]> threadLocalArray = new ThreadLocal<float[]>(()=>new float[200*1000]);

private void ComputationWithThreadLocal(float[] result)
{
  var _lock = new object();
  Parallel.For(0, 50, x =>
  {
    var subResult = threadLocalArray.Value;
    CalculateSubResult(subResult);

    lock (_lock)
      for (int i = 0; i < subResult.Length; i++)
        result[i] += subResult[i];

     Array.Clear(subResult,0,subResult.Length);
  });
}
```

There are two problems with this approach:

1. Over time (and this is a part of a long running computation) `threadLocalArray` stores more and more arrays, even if there are only few logical cores, which leads to a memory leak. I cannot call `threadLocalArray.Dispose()` until the computation is finished, so there is no way to prevent it from growing.
2. Summing subcomputation results requires lock and is wasteful. I would like to have a local per-thread sum, and only after thread finishes its partitioned work, the summation should occur.

There is an overload method which deals with 2.

```
public static ParallelLoopResult For<TLocal>(
    int fromInclusive,
    int toExclusive,
    Func<TLocal> localInit,
    Func<int, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> body,
    Action<TLocal> localFinally
)
```

The `Func<TLocal> localInit` would just init a subResult array like so: `()=>new float[200*1000]`. In that case the `Action<TLocal> localFinally` executes only one per partition, which is more efficient. But the problem here is that `localInit` cannot use `()=>threadLocalArray.Value` to get thread local array, because if Parallel.For loops are recursively nested then the same array is used for subcomputation at diffrent nest levels, leading to incorrect results.

I think I'm looking for something like this (CachedArrayProvider is a class that needs to manage reusing arrays):

```
Parallel.For(0,50, 
  ()=>CachedArrayProvider.GetArray(), 
  (i, localArray) => {/*body*/},
  (localArray) =>
  {
    //do final sum here
    CachedArrayProvider.ReturnArray(localArray);
  }
);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `ConcurrentBag<float[]> bag = new ConcurrentBag<float[]>()`, `() => { float[] localArray; if(!bag.TryTake(out localArray)) { localArray = new float[200*1000] } return localArray; }`, `localArray => { /*do final sum here*/ bag.Add(localArray); }`

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks. I'm still left with ~50 items in the bag after computation finishes, despite having 6 core machine.

Comment: IMHO, you do not need nested parallel loops. One level of parallel would be enough to take up all cores. And it possible be faster due to less overhead.